# Is there any way to use AdWords with CodeIgnitor (or similar)?

Tags: advertising, codeigniter

I am working with a website that uses CodeIgnitor, a content management system I hadn't heard of before.  The problem:  Incoming links from AdWords contain a long query string, and if you add a query string to the requested URL, CodeIgnitor thinks that that's part of the page it has to fetch, so it returns a "Page not found" for anyone who comes in from AdWords.

Another problem:  Google AdWords doesn't allow you to link to a page that redirects (locally or remotely), although someone can enlighten me if this isn't always true.

So, if anyone has any idea for how to solve this, either by changing AdWords settings, CodeIgnitor settings, or other hacks, it would be appreciated...

Comment: Might be better asking on Stack Overflow, for the CodeIgniter side anyway.

Comment: Yeah, this involves CI controller hackery. You would probably get a better response on SO.

Comment: CodeIgnitor is a PHP framework - not a content management system. Are you thinking of ExpressionEngine (a CMS built atop CI)?

Comment: Thanks - It is CodeIgnitor, that just shows how little I know about it.  I thought it was more relevant here than StackOverflow because I wasn't really interested in changing any actual code, just working with this or AdWords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the router object of codeignitor. The relevant documentation is found here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Besides changing the CMS-code you can also disable [Adwords Auto tagging](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55590). This will not append any extra parameters to the target url.

Comment: I will try the first thing, but since we are using Analytics as well, I'll have to see if I can do that without auto-tagging before I try that.